# Allocating more memory to an existing Global memory array

Tags: memory-management, cuda

is it possible to add memory to a previously allocated array in global memory?

what i need to do is this:

```
//cudamalloc memory for d_A
int n=0;int N=100;
do
{
 Kernel<<< , >>> (d_A,n++);
 //add N memory to d_A
 while(n!=5)}
```

does doing another cudamalloc removes the values of the previously allocated array? in my case the values of the previous allocated array should be kept...

Comment: if you are not extremely comfortable with malloc, realloc, and free (to name a few) in c, you will find it impossible to write CUDA programs. one thing at a time!!

Answer (score 5):

First, cudaMalloc behaves like malloc, not realloc. This means that cudaMalloc will allocate totally new device memory at a new location. There is no realloc function in the cuda API.

Secondly, as a workaround, you can just use cudaMalloc again to allocate more more memory. Remember to free the device pointer with cudaFree before you assign a new address to `d_a`. The following code is *functionally* what you want.

```
int n=0;int N=100;

//set the initial memory size
size = <something>;

do
{
    //allocate just enough memory
    cudaMalloc((void**) &d_A, size);

    Kernel<<< ... >>> (d_A,n++);   

    //free memory allocated for d_A
    cudaFree(d_A);

    //increase the memory size
    size+=N;

while(n!=5)}
```

Thirdly, cudaMalloc can be an expensive operation, and I expect the above code will be rather slow. I think you should consider why you want to grow the array. Can you allocate memory for `d_A` one time with enough memory for the largest use case? There is likely no reason to allocate only 100 bytes if you know you need 1,000 bytes later on!

```
//calculate the max memory requirement
MAX_SIZE = <something>;

//allocate only once
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_A, MAX_SIZE);

//use for loops when they are appropriate
for(n=0; n<5; n++)
{
    Kernel<<< ... >>> (d_A,n);
}
```

Comment: +1 for "There is no reason to allocate only 100 bytes if you know you need 1,000 bytes later on!"

Answer (score 3):

Your psuedocode does not "add memory to a previously allocated array" at all. The standard C way of increasing the size of an existing allocation is via the realloc() function, and there is no CUDA equivalent of realloc() at the time of writing.

When you do

```
cudaMalloc(d_A....)

// something

cudaMalloc(d_A....)
```

all you are doing is creating a new memory allocation and assigning it to d_A. The previous memory allocation still exists, but now you have lost the pointer value of the previous memory and have no way of accessing it. Based on this and your previous question on almost the same subject, might I suggest you spend a bit of time revising memory and pointer concepts in C before you try CUDA, because unless you have a very clear understanding of these fundamentals, you will find the distributed memory nature of CUDA to be very confusing,

Comment: lighten up - the comment `//add N memory to d_A` is meant to be pseudocode for the nonexistent cuda realloc function.

Comment: @jim-balter i think talonmies has everything right except for the very first sentence

Comment: @jmilloy Regardless of the accuracy of the first sentence, your "lighten up" was rude and uncalled for.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what complications cuda adds to the mix(?) but in c you can't add memory to an already allocated array.

If you want to grow a malloc'd array, you need to malloc a new array of the size you need and copy the contents from the existing array.

If you're doing this often then it's probably worth mallocing more than you need each time to avoid costly (in terms of processing time) re-allocation operations.

Comment: `realloc` adds memory to an already `malloc`ed array. However, there is no cudaMalloc so your answer does happen to apply.

Comment: I believe `realloc` only behaves like that if there's sufficcient space left in the current block. Otherwise, it just allocates the new space and copies across the old data exactly as I described above.

Comment: You believe incorrectly. `realloc` extends the block if there is unallocated space following it (if not then of course it must relocate the block). The point is that your statement "If you want to grow ..." is incorrect and is the wrong way to do it because `realloc` is *often* much more efficient, and is certainly easier and less error-prone to code.

Comment: Right, I see what you're getting at now. I'll leave this answer up as an example of what not to do...